# Get subarray from bi-dimensional array in just one line

Tags: python, arrays, find

I have a problem trying to find and get and array from a bi dimensional array in python.
I don't pretend to use a for structure for example in order to get this. Someone knows how to get this array in just one or a few lines of code?.

Thanks.

There is an example:

```
my_dimensional_array = [(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c'))]
```

I need to return

```
my_single_array_from_1 = [(1,'a'),(1,'b')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to select those elements in `my_dimensional_array` whose first value equals 1:

```
In [16]: my_dimensional_array = [(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c')]

In [17]: [item for item in my_dimensional_array if item[0]==1]
Out[17]: [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to exclude the last element, you can use [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/1903116) like this

```
my_dimensional_array = [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
print my_dimensional_array[:-1]
# [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as:

```
result = [(i,j) for i,j in my_dimensional_array if i==1]
```